# C Preprocessor, jumping out of #ifdef

Tags: c, preprocessor

I am currently learning C and I came across this question I can't find an answer to.

Can I jump out of a #ifdef without going through the #endif?
For example can I do this:

```
   char getOS( void ) {
       /* Returns the user Operating System
       */

       #ifdef _WIN32
           return 'w';

       #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
           return 'm';

       #elif __linux__
           return 'l';

       #else
           raiseError( "You cannot play on this OS", true );

       #endif

   }
```

Comment: Add (e.g.) `return 0;` after `raiseError` to have all paths use a `char` return. Otherwise your code is fine.

Comment: What do you mean by "jump out of"?  In an `#if...#elif...#else` chain, only one will be selected.

Comment: `cpp` conditionals (e.g. `#ifdef`, `#elif`) are not like C `if` statements. They do not generate all possibilities like `if` would. The `#ifdef` "selects" code in the first compilation stage. So, _if_ `_WIN32` is defined, the later compile stages will see [only]: `char getOS( void ) { return 'w'; }` and compile that. You may want to replace `raiseError( "You cannot play on this OS", true );` with `#error You cannot play on this OS` so the _compilation_ fails if you're compiling on an unsupported system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the preprocessor a bit.  Remember, the preprocessor runs *before* the compiler.  So this function is going to look like one of the following when it gets to the compiler:

```c
char getOS( void ) {
        return 'w';
}
```

```c
char getOS( void ) {
        return 'm';
}
```

```c
char getOS( void ) {
        return 'l';
}
```

```c
char getOS( void ) {
        raiseError( "You cannot play on this OS", true );
}
```

... and these are all valid. Well I don't know what `raiseError` does, but if it isn't a macro that `return`s or `exit`s, you will want to add an extra `return` to the end of the function for the `#else` branch.

The point is, none of that `#if`, `#elif`, etc is going to the compiler anyway, so you are never "jumping out".  If you want to see for yourself, you can add a compiler option to only do preprocessing (and no compiling).  I know for `gcc`, that option is `-E`.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Finally I'm understanding what the preprocessor really does

Answer (score 3):

If by "jump out of", you mean cause the compiler to give an error, you can do that with the `#error` directive.

```
   #ifdef _WIN32
       return 'w';

   #elif TARGET_OS_MAC
       return 'm';

   #elif __linux__
       return 'l';

   #else
       #error "You cannot play on this OS"

   #endif
```

Comment: By "jump out of" I meant that if the first condition is true than I would have never reached #endif and I thought that might have been a problem. Now I understand better what the prepocessor really does. Your solution is still useful tho. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confusing preprocessor with runtime behavior: they are not the same.

The preprocessor runs *before* the actual compiler (at least conceptually; in practice they can very well be the same program of course). It affects the source that the compiler then sees.

You cannot "go through" the `#endif`, it's not there when the program runs. You will either have a `return`, or a call to `raiseError()`.

Comment: Thank you too. Now I finally got it :)